# Google Map not displaying completely

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-maps

So we have a reactjs app, built on rails api and we're using a google map, rendered with reactjs, however for some reason if you visit https://justbooked-staging.herokuapp.com/listings?q=tacos&location=16%20Aladdin%20Crescent,%20Richmond%20Hill,%20ON,%20Canada&lat=43.8986289&lng=-79.448373 and click "Map View" you will see some grey under the Google Map.

Edit - image attached, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfwpL.png)

We'd like to fix this, but are struggling to find the solution.

The map container is set by css, but map rendering is not... javascript render's the map.. and this is because of changing tabs (list view and map view) are like tabs.

With that said, I don't think setting the map container would fix the issue. I noticed that if you scroll up or down the page, then map shows up entire space properly

Any ideas? It's been holding us back for a few days!

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any gray under the map ? What's your web browser ?

Comment: @AlexVand Attached an example, seems to be happening in Chrome and Safari. It happens when you click map view and scroll down.

Comment: https://ibb.co/nhekE6, With Google Chrome. Edit: Okay, tested with firefox and I can see the gray under the map. But with safari I have no gray zone.

Comment: May be you could use gmap.checkResize() ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` after you switch to the tab and after you loaded your map.

The problem comes when the map renders in a non-visible `<div>`, then gets funky.